# How can we screen by user groups from Okta on .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, okta

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC for a web app and using a policy to screen pages. When I create a requirement, I'm able to find all of the regular claims that come with OpenID Connect (name, ver, iss, aud, iat, etc.) but not groups, even though I've added groups in the OpenID Connect token configuration in Okta.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{        
    services.AddAuthorization(options => {
        options.AddPolicy("ActionPrivilegeRequired", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ActionPrivilegeRequirement()));
    });
}
```

ActionPrivilegeRequirement.cs:

```
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ActionPrivilegeRequirement requirement)
    {
        var groupMembership = context.User.FindFirst(
            c => c.Type == "groups").Value;

        // ...
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

What do I need to do to add an Okta user's group membership to the user object's claims?

---

**Update**:

I've updated the OpenId middleware to include groups in the scope:

```
            OpenIdConnectOptions opts = new OpenIdConnectOptions()
            {
                //...
            };
            opts.Scope.Clear();
            opts.Scope.Add("openid");
            opts.Scope.Add("profile");
            opts.Scope.Add("groups");
```

and confirmed that the server request to [Okta endpoint]/oauth2/v1/token and the client request to /authorize include groups, but still haven't found groups in the claims.

Comment: Hiya, did you even get this working?

Comment: @Ewan yeah -- we ended up creating an Okta group to mirror the Active Directory group, since only Okta groups were getting picked up. See comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839653/how-can-we-screen-by-user-groups-from-okta-on-net-core?noredirect=1#comment70910366_41840035)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not doing this already - did you add the [groups](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc.html#scopes) scope to the [/authorize](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc.html#authentication-request) request? It looks like you've configured the groups on the Okta admin side, but need to request it from the client as well.

If you are requesting the groups scope, there are some other things to look into:

1. Do you have more than 100 groups that would be returned? There is a note at the bottom of [scope dependent claims](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc.html#scope-dependent-claims-not-always-returned) doc that talks about this limit.
2. If you verify that you are making the request with the groups scope, and it's still not working - can you check the id_token that is returned from Okta and verify whether it includes the groups or not? If it does, then this could be a bug in the .NET sdk (which we can open an issue for).

Comment: Good question. I added groups to the scope  through the `OpenIdConnectOptions` object, but I have not sniffed out whether that is adding the proper scope to the /authorize request. Is there documentation on properly updating scope when using `OpenIdConnectMiddleware`?

Comment: Looks like you've confirmed that you're sending the scopes in the /authorize request - to debug a bit more, can you check the scopes that are returned in the /token request? I.e. in [this example of a successful response](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc.html#response-example-success-3), Okta will return the id_token and the scopes in the response object - I'm wondering if the "groups" scope shows up there, but when you decode the id_token there are no corresponding groups.

Comment: Yes, the groups scope is definitely showing up in there, I'm going to try to decode id_token next and see what comes up. In the meantime, though, I noticed that this request is to /token, not /authorize, so I may try to dig more to get that request as well.

Comment: New update: I've just updated the code and I'm getting a groups claim, but it only includes the first of my groups, strangely.

Comment: Did you add the missing groups on the Okta side? The id_token will return the groups in the intersection of the groups you have configured on the Okta side, and the groups you are requesting in the scope when making the /authorize + /token request (which if it's coming back in the /token response, suggests that you are requesting the groups scope correctly).

Comment: Yeah, we reached this conclusion -- all the invisible groups are AD groups. Is there a way to make an Okta group that auto-updates with the contents of an AD group?

Comment: Just to double check - the AD group that is missing matches the filter you've set up for Groups claim on the app's Sign On page right?

Comment: Yes -- the group filter is regex .* (though I did try other filters to make sure that wasn't the issue). The only group returned was a lone Okta-managed group, and none of the AD ones.

Comment: Just checked with the team - it looks like this is a known issue (there's an open jira to add support for AD groups)

Comment: good to know I'm not going crazy. :) Any way I can subscribe to that?

Comment: Good question - I think the followup is to send an email to developers@okta.com to open a support case.

Comment: If you cannot see Active Directory groups but you can see native Okta groups (create a test one) do show up, see Jonathan Bahnick's post that suggests creating an expression: Groups.contains("active_directory","My-Group-Prefix",100)
 
https://support.okta.com/help/s/question/0D50Z00008G7UrPSAV/groups-not-available-in-openid-connect-claims?language=en_US&t=1597267473225

Answer (score 0):

FYI 2.0 no longer adds everything from the user info endpoint due to cookie bloat. To get groups to show up in my claims I added this to the AddOpenIdConnect options...

```
options.ClaimActions.Add(new CustomJsonClaimAction(ClaimTypes.Role, ClaimTypes.Role, (x) => string.Join(",", x["groups"].Values<string>())));
```